# Ruby String.gsub perlism $1 $2 $N thread safe?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have been looking all over the interwebs for an answer to the following question and have not found anything. Can someone possibly answer this?

I am learning Ruby, and am curious about the String.gsub block functionality. If you use a block with gsub you can access the RegExp matches by number using $1, $2, etc... However, based on what I am seeing, and how global variables in Ruby begin with $ I am assuming that using gsub in such a manner would not be thread-safe. Is this correct? Are the $1, $2, $N variables INDEED global?

```
"test stuff here".gsub(/(\w+)/) { "[#{$1}]" } #Thread safe?
```

Comment: tl;dr: Yes, thread safe, and no, not true globals.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you also for pointing out the duplicate. As I said, I was completely unable to find anything. :)